# Как словить событие конкретного объекта в Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, события, focus

В `Grid` есть несколько объектов, некоторые поля лежат друг на друге. Как можно прописать событие нажатия мыши конкретно на один объект?

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="990" >
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="900"  Panel.ZIndex="0" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" />
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Panel.ZIndex="3" Height="469" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="900" >
        <Canvas x:Name="CanvasInvisible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="886" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasPrice" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Panel.ZIndex="0" />
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="900" RenderTransformOrigin="0.74,2.505" Margin="0,412,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Нужен именно в первом `Canvas` обработать событие `MouseWheel`. По сути, на всём окне растянуты 3 объекта : `Grid`, первый `Canvas` и `ScrollViewer`. В итоге ловит Focus самый главный. И ладно с этим фокусом. Мне нужно еще и обработать событие прокрутки колесика конкретно на данном объекте. Хочу сделать в итоге масштабирование изображения на `Canvas`

Comment: Поставьте остальным элементам `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

Comment: Всё, спасибо) Еще в данном объекте было свойство `Focusable = false`, также поменял)

Comment: Окей, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, мышиные события обычно* доставляются самому верхнему элементу, который находится под мышью (процесс поиска называется *hit testing*). Если у вас в `Grid`'е несколько элементов, то каждый следующий элемент «выше» предыдущего.

Для того, чтобы эти остальные элементы не учитывались при поиске целевого элемента для мышиных событий, поставьте им атрибут `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

---

*за исключением случая mouse capture

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло решить мою проблему, теперь заработало всё!) Премного благодарен. Вот только еще 1, я поставил событие на `Canvas`, а оно срабатывает у меня, если я нажимаю именно на созданные объекты, а не на само поле `Canvas`. Как это можно изменить? Мне нужно, чтобы выскакивало событие именно на всём поле, а не на созданных объектах.

Comment: @Fresto: Точно так же? Объекты, которые на канвасе, «выше» его, так что можно убрать у них `IsHitTestVisible`. Ну или можно ловить PreviewMouseDown, он доставляется сначала родительским объектам.